# VSCode で turtle をインポートしたいが一瞬だけ turtle のキャンバスが出てきて消えてしまう

Tags: python

教科書にはIDLEを使ってコードを入力しろとなっているのですがIDLEはあまり好みません。Visual Studio Codeでなんとかなりませんか？ついでにIDLEで下のコードを入力するとうまくいきます。turtleはもしかしてIDLEでしか動かないのでしょうか。

```
import turtle

t=turtle.Pen()
```

プログラミング初心者で初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。何か知っている方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[Turtle Graphic Window not working from VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59004671/9014308) あるいは単に最初に[turtle.Turtle()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.Turtle)を実行せずに直接`turtle.Pen()`を呼び出しているからかもしれません。こんな例も参考に。[タートルグラフィックの作図方法が分からない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62858/26370)

Comment: わざわざ英語版のstack・overflowに載せていただきありがとうございました。お陰様で無事に解決することができました。VS codeでturtleを使う場合は最後にinputを使えばいいのですね。いい発見になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

4行目がミソ

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
timy = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```